# How to check whether two unit vectors are parallel?

Tags: vectors, coordinate-systems

Lets say we have the vectors, $3\hat i+3\hat{j}$ and $5\hat i+5\hat j$. Are these vectors parallel?
Is this process is similar to the equations of lines?
$3x+3y-9=0$ etc.

So if I have a vector $a=3i+λj$ and $b=(λ-1)i+2j$, and we need to find lambda so that they are parallel. So can I just compare the constants and get the answer or follow the dot product of vectors and find the answer (since the angle between the vectors is $0°$)?

Sorry for asking a very simple problem.

Comment: Their coefficients will be proportional. Yes quite similar to equation of lines.

Comment: so if i have a vector a=3i+λj and b=(λ-1)i+2j, and we need to find lambda so that they are parallel. so can i just compare the constants and get the answer or follow the dot product of vectors and find the answer(since the angle between the vectors is 0°)

Comment: As danimal says in his answer. :)

Comment: Note that our vectors are **not unit** as you write in the title (unit means that the modulis is $1$). If two vectors are unit and parallele than these are the same vector.

Answer (score 1):

We know they are parallel because one vector is equal to the other but only multiplied by a constant number. Each vector will also have the same ratio between corresponding components.

Comment: so if i have a vector a=3i+λj and b=(λ-1)i+2j, and we need to find lambda so that they are parallel. so can i just compare the constants and get the answer or follow the dot product of vectors and find the answer(since the angle between the vectors is 0)

Comment: You can say 3 over lambda is equal to lambda-1 over 2

Comment: thanks. so its like coordinate geometry right?